# C#/WPF Binding data from one table in a DataSet to two DataGrids. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset

I have a `DataSet` in my project and I want to make two `DataGrid` with data from one table.

On this table I have a column with values being 0 or 1 and with that I want to show two different `DataGrid`: one showing only rows with 0s and another with 1s.

So what Im doing is this:

```
defaultDataSet.AudioDataTable audio_table = new defaultDataSet.AudioDataTable();
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + configurations_folder + AppDbFile);
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Audio WHERE Type = 0");
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Fill(audio_table);
con.Close();

defaultDataSet.AudioDataTable audio_customized_table = new defaultDataSet.AudioDataTable();
con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + configurations_folder + AppDbFile);
con.Open();
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Audio WHERE Type = 1");
adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Fill(audio_customized_table);
con.Close();
```

So how can I do to bind `audio_table` and `audio_customized_table` to both DataGrids? Should I use something like a `CollectionViewSource`? If yes, how?

**EDIT**

Here are both `DataGrid` on my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid   x:Name="AudioReservedDataGrid" 
            ColumnHeaderHeight="60" 
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AudioViewSource}}"  
            RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
            Loaded="AudioReservedDataGrid_Loaded" 
            CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
            Height="500" 
            CanUserSortColumns="False">

<DataGrid   x:Name="AudioCustomizedDataGrid" 
            ColumnHeaderHeight="60" 
            CanUserAddRows="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AudioViewSource}}" 
            RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
            CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
            Height="500" 
            CanUserSortColumns="False" 
            RowEditEnding="AudioCustomizedDataGrid_RowEditEnding" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="True">
```

I'm almost sure the problem is on `ItemsSource` but I dont know how to bind my tables as I need.

Comment: as a side note: lots of reused code, you could put it in a method.

Comment: Hey @MattBeldon! I know its not the best coding but Im kinda new to this. Thanks for your suggestion! :)

Comment: Could you show us your .xaml code?

Comment: @MattBeldon I updated the post with my XAML code

Comment: when you compile do you get any binding errors?

Comment: No but it doesnt show what i want. In both DataGrids i get the same rows... I know I'm doing something wrong. Im trying to figure out what it is

Comment: they wont be so obvious to spot, look through the debug output and look for something like `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'AudioViewSource' property not found on 'object'`  if not then it's just not pushing the update to the frontend, so `ItemSource` would not be the issue

Comment: I dont see that error on my debug output. But im almost sure it is because im not saving my queries properly on viewsource... Maybe im wrong... Anyway i found something like this and im editing my code: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4692a852-9b88-4b5b-9b1e-cf63c7127ee5/two-datagrids-one-source-table-binding-problem?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to solve this issue. I needed to do two different `DataTable` and work from there to filter what I want and also two different `CollectionViewSource` as I'm showing on my code:

```
//AUDIO DEFAULT
AudioTableAdapter databaseDataSetAudioDefaultTableAdapter = new AudioTableAdapter();
databaseDataSetAudioDefaultTableAdapter.Fill(databaseDataSet.Audio);
defaultDataSet.AudioDataTable audio_table = new defaultDataSet.AudioDataTable();
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + configurations_folder + AppDbFile)) 
{
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Audio WHERE Type = 0");
    using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
        adapter.Fill(audio_table);
}
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource AudioDefaultViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("AudioDefaultViewSource")));
AudioDefaultViewSource.Source = audio_table;
AudioDefaultViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();

//AUDIO CUSTOMIZED
AudioTableAdapter databaseDataSetAudioCustomizedTableAdapter = new AudioTableAdapter();
databaseDataSetAudioCustomizedTableAdapter.Fill(databaseDataSet.Audio);
defaultDataSet.AudioDataTable audio_customized_table = new defaultDataSet.AudioDataTable();
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + configurations_folder + AppDbFile))
{
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Audio WHERE Type = 1");
    using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
        adapter.Fill(audio_customized_table);
}
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource AudioCustomizedViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("AudioCustomizedViewSource")));
AudioCustomizedViewSource.Source = audio_customized_table;
AudioCustomizedViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

And in .xaml:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AudioDefaultViewSource" Source="{Binding Audio, Source={StaticResource databaseDataSet}}"/>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AudioCustomizedViewSource" Source="{Binding Audio, Source={StaticResource databaseDataSet}}"/>

<DataGrid 
    x:Name="AudioReservedDataGrid" 
    ColumnHeaderHeight="60" 
    CanUserAddRows="False" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AudioDefaultViewSource}}"  
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
    Loaded="AudioReservedDataGrid_Loaded" 
    CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
    CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
    Height="500" 
    CanUserSortColumns="False">

<DataGrid 
    x:Name="AudioCustomizedDataGrid" 
    ColumnHeaderHeight="60" 
    CanUserAddRows="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AudioCustomizedViewSource}}" 
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"      
    CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
    CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
    Height="500" 
    CanUserSortColumns="False"
    RowEditEnding="AudioCustomizedDataGrid_RowEditEnding"         
    CanUserDeleteRows="True">
```